# How to export mail message to EML or MSG file with PowerShell and EWS part 2

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, eml

I am trying to export all messages in the inbox of a particular account in Exchange 2010. I found this solution in another post [How to export mail message to EML or MSG file with PowerShell and EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653778/how-to-export-mail-message-to-eml-or-msg-file-with-powershell-and-ews/42654448#42654448?newreg=7bb9bd76c00644408000cff703b0e98f) that looks very promising but I am getting an error while running the script. I am new to using EWS and I am a little lost.

Here is a copy of the code I am currently using:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

$strMailboxName = "Mailbox@domain.com"
$strSaveLocation = "\\server\share"

$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP1)
$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind
$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())

$MailboxName = get-mailbox -Identity $strMailboxName

$folderidcnt = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString())
$rootfolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service, $folderidcnt)


$offset = 0;
$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(10000, $offset)

$response = $service.LoadPropertiesForItems($results, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)

foreach ($mail in $results){

if ($mail.ToString() -eq "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage") {
    $mailSubject = $mail.Subject
    $mailProps = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::MimeContent)
    $mail.Load($mailProps)
    #TODO: clean up $mailSubject so it's filesystem friendly
    $fStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream("$strSaveLocatoin\$mailSubject.eml", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
    $fStream.Write($mail.MimeContent.Content, 0, $mail.MimeContent.Content.Length)
    $fStream.Close()
}
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Exception calling "LoadPropertiesForItems" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items"
At C:\PowershellScripts\Exchange-SaveEMailAsFile.ps1:23 char:44
+ $response = $service.LoadPropertiesForItems <<<< ($results, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet]::FirstC
lassProperties)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PowershellScripts\Exchange-SaveEMailAsFile.ps1:27 char:19
+ if ($mail.ToString <<<< () -eq "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage") {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ToString:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I have annonymized the 2 $str variables in the beginning of the script but other than that the code is as I have posted.

I would have liked to add a comment to the original post, but I do not yet have enough reputation.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error and code don't exactly line up for me. You have `$view` in your code where I see `$results` in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the output from a different run. I was moving around some variables to see if it made any difference. I have edited my original post with the correct error message. My apologies.

Comment: Ok.. so `$results` has no value so that would create your error. I think you still have your variables mixed up.

Comment: I agree completely however this script was copied from the link in my original post, and there are no comments there that anything is amiss. I really wish I could comment on that original post since those are the people who wrote and are using the script. I am not familiar enough with EWS to follow the logic of this script other than the fact that $results is currently a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`LoadPropertiesForItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems(v=exchg.80).aspx) expects that the first variable passed contains that items object and `$result` is not populated in that code so that is why you are getting the errors. You can see an example of this from the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services/).

I have tested the following which work for getting each mail from the Inbox of the mailbox connected to the Exchange service called `$exchangeService`. You will need to change several variables in this code to match yours. This was done on purpose so that you can see how things are workings.

It is possible this code could be better as my experience with this is also limited. Since it is not hard and needed to be done for a good test I have addressed this comment with some regex : *#TODO: clean up $mailSubject so it's filesystem friendly*. The one thing that is *not* done here is logic to account for files with blank subjects. Currently they will overwrite eachother and you will end up with a single ".eml" file of that last one like that processed.

```
# Folder that will contain the eml files. 
$destinationFolder = "E:\temp\test"

# Create the view. Set for 1000 paged items
$pageSize = 1000
$itemView = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView]::New($pageSize)
$itemView.PropertySet =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$mimeView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::MimeContent)

# Bind to the root folder
$rootFolderID = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
$boundRootFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($exchangeService,$rootFolderID)

# regex to remove illegal characters in the subject that are not allowed in the ntfs file system
$regex = ([char[]]'<>:"/\|?*' | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)})-join"|"

# Loop through paging results
do{
    # Get the next batch of results
    $filterResults = $boundRootFolder.FindItems($itemView)

    # We need to process each mail in this set of results
    $filterResults.Items | ForEach-Object{
        # Get the subject before we change the view
        $mailSubject = $_.Subject -replace $regex

        # Load the properties for the view create earlier
        $_.Load($mimeView)

        # Using a file stream to export this single messages mime content 
        write-host "$destinationFolder\$mailSubject.eml" -ForegroundColor Green
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream("$destinationFolder\$mailSubject.eml", [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $stream.Write($_.MimeContent.Content, 0, $_.MimeContent.Content.Length)
        $stream.Close()
    }

    # Loop if there are still more results in the filter. Adjust the filter offset. 
    $itemView.Offset += $filterResults.Items.Count
} while($filterResults.MoreAvailable)
```

My first issue is that I should be able to load the required properties at the same time but I do not know how to do that hence there are technically two load operations. First during the initial find then once more in the loop to get the mime content. This is likely how it has to be done since if you tried to do it all at once you get an error

```
The property MimeContent can't be used in FindItem requests.
```

I would have a real good look at [Glen's blog on the EWS API](http://gsexdev.blogspot.ca/2016/03/ews-basics-enumerating-all-items-in-any.html). Lots of good information with examples. When I was struggling that is what gave me a firm ground on how the EWS API works. He is also a user on here I have seen from time to time.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely be checking out that blog. I appreciate the assistance.